# Opposite of wavelet transform?

Tags: fourier-transform, wavelet

[image: STFT and Wavelet]

Wavelet transform gives good time resolution for high-frequency events and good frequency resolution for low-frequency events.

=> I want to have complete opposite of wavelet transform, where I get good time resolution for low frequency events? Is there any known transform or specific window to get it?

Comment: Multiply your signal with the alternating sequence (-1,1,-1,1,..) before applying the wavelet transform. That will flip the frequency axis.

Comment: The solution is simple: repeatedly decompose the H subband rather than the L subband. In order to better understand the idea, see also the wavelet packet decomposition.

Answer (score -2):

wavelet transform also serves to you what you want to do, all you have to do is to first apply a low-pass your signal so as to keep the frequency range you want to scan only, another approach is to transform Gabor where you have to define the size and shape of the analysis window, but I would recommend better  using wavelet transform applying a lowpass filter your signal first.